# Como resolver o conflito entre AngularJS e Django?

Tags: angularjs, django

Qual a forma mais eficiente para resolver o problema de conflito entre Django e AngularJS ao usar `{{ }}` nos templates?

Comment: Único jeito é mudando o código fonte de um dos dois, para que por exemplo o Angular reconheça `[[ ]]` e Django `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O AngularJS oferece ferramentas para configuração dos marcadores via `$interpolateProvider`. Por exemplo, caso você queira utilizar `[[` e `]]` como marcadores, utilize o seguinte snippet:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

Fonte do snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923521/angular-js-custom-delimiter

Comment: Só cuide com os símbolos que utilizar como marcadores, para não criar algo tipo isso: `<span>[[array[myIndex]]]</span>` (em um linha já fica estranho, imagine em varias).

Comment: @Fernando correto - em teoria você pode utilizar qualquer combinação, inclusive algumas que sejam apenas alterações parciais como `{*` e `*}`.